# Can someone tell me why this JSfiddle repeats the first song when finishes playing?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, audio

This is a super quick question. Here is a piece of code that plays an array of songs in order. Somehow, when the array finishes playing, it repeats the first song. Any idea why? I am going insane because I cant figure it out...

Code below in the link: https://jsfiddle.net/wt2joay4/

```
var song1 = $('#sound-1');
var song2 = $('#sound-2');
var song3 = $('#sound-3');

var audioArray = [song1, song2, song3];
var i=0;
var lastPlayedFile = null;
$(".click").click(function(){
  if(lastPlayedFile !== null) {
     lastPlayedFile[1].currentTime = 0;
     lastPlayedFile.trigger('pause'); 
  }
  if (i< audioArray.length){
     lastPlayedFile = audioArray[i];
     audioArray[i].trigger('play');
     i++;
} else if (i>=audioArray.length){
     i = 0;
     lastPlayedFile = audioArray[0];
     audioArray[i].trigger('play');
  };
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Last `if`: `i=0`  TBH seems a bit backward, as `i` = *next* index to play rather than a more sensible *currently* playing index.

Comment: @freedomn-m Removing it won't allow me to keep playing the array, unfortunately :S

Comment: Had another look: it goes 0,1,2,0,0,1,2 - so the first one is played twice when it loops round - is that the issue?

Comment: @freedomn-m Correct, that's the issue unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `i=0`.  This should be `i=1`.

The `i` variable is used to indicate which song to play *next* rather than current index.

So in `i<audioArray.length` it plays `audioArray[i]` and *then* does `i++`.

But in `i>=length` it plays `audioArray[0]` but leaves `i` pointing at 0, so the *next* played is again 0.

The fix is to leave `i=1` after re-looping.  This could use the same concept as above: `i=0; ...play [i]...; i++;` or just `i=1`.

```
} else if (i>=audioArray.length){
     lastPlayedFile = audioArray[0];
     audioArray[i].trigger('play');
     i = 1;
  };
});
```

---

Suggestion: Use a better variable name than `i`.  If this was named `nextIndex` then `nextIndex=0` would be clear(er) that it's going to play 0 next (when it's already playing 0).

Alternative suggestion: Keep `i` as the *current* index and increase before starting the next, eg:

```
var song1 = $('#sound-1');
var song2 = $('#sound-2');
var song3 = $('#sound-3');

var audioArray = [song1, song2, song3];
var i = -1;
$(".click").click(function() {

  if (i >= 0) {
    audioArray[i].currentTime = 0;
    audioArray[i].trigger('pause');
  }

  i++;
  if (i >= audioArray.length)
    i = 0;

  audioArray[i].trigger('play');
});
```

(and change `i` to `currentIndex`, but left as `i` above to compare with original)

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zaL9u2o4/)